# How can I use hashbytes like checksum?

Tags: sql-server, hash, checksum

In SQL server, we can easily generate a hash on an entire row using "checksum":

```
select 
checksum(*), *    
from mytable
```

Is there a way to do the same thing using the hashbytes function?
Something like:

```
select 
hashbytes('md5', *), *    
from mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

Not easily I'm afraid. And in most cases you shouldn't really want to. But if you must, generating a XML document for each row and hashing the XML document is probably the easiest way to go:

```
SELECT  HASHBYTES('MD5', X.value)
FROM    Data
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT value = 
        CAST((SELECT Data.* FROM   (SELECT 1) AS X (y) FOR XML AUTO) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
) AS X
```

**EDIT:** I've did some testing, applying the `CAST(... AS VARCHAR(MAX))` as I've done in the updated statement above improves performance about 15%. More importantly, it prevents truncation errors on wide tables. Concatenating the columns yourself is even after this fix still about 15% faster. Using CONCAT() (available from MSSQL 2012) function makes your live a little easier though as you can omit applying ISNULL and CAST functions to each column.

Comment: Clever, and it has built-in protection against column content overlap as well. Whether it performs acceptably is another matter, though.

Answer (score 1):

If writing out the columns is no objection, you can simply concatenate the columns and hash that:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('md5', 
    ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), column1), 0x) +
    ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), column2), 0x) + 
    ...
)
```

From SQL Server 2012 onwards, we can achieve the same more compactly using `CONCAT` (thanks to @MWillemse for the tip):

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('md5', CONCAT(column1, column2, ...))
```

Be aware that this can cause collisions if your columns are "the same": hashing `AA,BB,CC` yields the same result as `AAB,BBC,C` or even `AABBCC,NULL,NULL`. If this is a concern, you'll have to design your own hashing scheme to minimize the odds of this (by including the column names in the hash, for example). Also, this is a binary checksum: hashing `A,B,C` is not the same as `a,b,c`. Again, if this is a concern you'll have to tweak the data before hashing it (`UPPER`).

Finally, MD5 is no longer considered cryptographically secure, so only use this for things like checksum indexes where you need less collision probability than with `CHECKSUM`. If you need a cryptographic signature of a row, this is too simplistic.

Comment: It might be worth adding a separator between the columns, e.g. '|~'. +1 for using CONCAT